# Is Obito on Sage Mode?

Tags: naruto

Recently in the manga, Uchiha Obito said that he sensed Sasuke concentrating chakra in his left eye and poof! He quickly defended himself in an instant with slight similarity to Naruto's Sage Mode, that's why I wonder if he is in Sage Mode. If not, where did his sensory ability come from?

[image]

**Update:**
Here's a proof of his transformation from Naruto Episode 640 Page 14:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure as to how he sensed the accumulation of chakra, but I am sure that bening a sensory type is not limited to sage mode. Naruto in his Nine Tails form is sensory type. So, if I were to draw similarities, then I would say with Obito being the jinchuriki of the 10 tailed beast he gained the sensory powers.

Comment: I agree. but I am disciplined enough to ask the question to confirm my theory.

Comment: I don't think he is on sage mode. That's a result of sealing the ten tails inside of him, same as naruto after he took over Kurama. You can see the similarities. :)

Comment: Also has a Rinnegan and Sharingan, and both can assess chakra, as stated by Itachi and shown by Madara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that I completely forgot. During Sasuke's battle with Deidara, Sasuke mentioned that using his Sharingan he can see chakra, so even Obito should be able to do the same, when Sasuke concentrated his chakra on his left eye, Obito could see it, thus he dodged it. He need not be in Sage Mode to accomplish that.

Comment: Good point. How about the markings and transformation?

Comment: The markings and transformations come from Obito becoming the Jinchuriki of the 10 tails. Naruto too faces similar transformations.

Comment: Therefore he is in Sage of Six Path mode and not in Sage Mode.=D

Comment: There is a difference in "being similar to the sage of the six paths " and being a sage. The sage of the six paths need not have been a sage, it can just be a phrase used as a title. Like Tsunade, Orochimaru and Jiraya were known as the sanins. Also as Naruto is known as Konoha's most surprising knuckle head ninja... :P

Comment: Yes I know. I was just kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Madara said this when Obito became the Jinchuuriki of the Juubi: Now he is equal to The Sage of Six Paths.

So yes, Obito was in Sage Mode after he had become the Jinchuuriki. But Sage Mode abilities of Obito are far more dangerous than that of any one else due to the massive chakra of the Juubi.

Comment: The fact that he's comparable to the Sage of Six Paths, doesn't mean he's in Sage Mode, the two are different kinds of "Sage".

Comment: Look at the marks on his body. They are the same as that of the sage o six paths-the marks that shows that on is in sage mode. Plus he is showing all the characteristic features of a sage- like taking less damage, more reflexes etc.

Comment: Those aren't Sage Mode marks, those are the seal marks, Naruto has them too when he's in Bijuu mode, he isn't in Sage Mode the whole time. Also, nearly any "Mode" in the series does that, not just Sage Mode. Sage mode requires the user to sit still, and don't move. Obito has yet to do that.

Comment: Sage mode doesn't require person to stay still. When did Hashi ever stood still to get into his sage mode? Sage mode means the wielding of nature's chakra.

Comment: I agree @MadaraUchiha,. But don't you think that his transformation from a snake-like creature is a prerequisite for being in Sage Mode? We need more evidence though.

Comment: As far as i know sage modes in the series are used by Jiraiya, Naruto, Hashirama and Kabuto. There is no evidence yet to suggest that Obito is in sage mode now. He might be little short of becoming Sage of Six paths, doesnt mean he is in sage mode!

Comment: As for If Hashi stood still, He created a mass of wood clones, He could have gone to sage mode same way naruto did with his clones

Comment: @Morpheus: Hashi created a mass of wood clones after he was in sage mode and after the barrier of the four red suns was made and to help others to get in through the barrier. He was completely mobile before that. So he never stood still.

Answer (score 0):

He does go into sage mode, that is how he can access the truth seeking balls, and not be affected by touching them

Comment: Sage of Six Paths mode is different from Sage Mode. What you're referring to is SoSP mode.